# Skip attributes in XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

Currently I use the following approach to deserialize a RESTful XML return:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Part", Namespace = "")]
public class Part
{
   [DataMember(Order = 1)]
   public string ItemId { get; set; }
   [DataMember(Order = 2)]
   public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
   [DataMember(Order = 3)]
   public string Weight { get; set; }
}

public bool GetPartInformation(string itemId)
{
   var URL = "...some URL...";
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

   HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       Part part = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Part>().Result;

       Console.WriteLine("ItemId: {0}", part.ItemId);
       Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", part.ItemDescription);
       Console.WriteLine("Weight: {0}", part.Weight);

       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
       return false;
   }
}
```

This is the XML return:

```
<Part>  
    <ItemId>12345</ItemId>  
    <ItemDescription>Item Description</ItemDescription>  
    <Weight>0.5</Weight>  
    <Cost>190.59</Cost>  
</Part>
```

If I don't want to grab the ItemId in `public class Part` it unfortunately does not work to simply remove these two lines from `public class Part`:

```
[DataMember(Order = 1)]
public string ItemId { get; set; }
```

1) What is the correct approach to skip the ItemId attribute?
2) What would be the the easiest way to access `Cost` only and omit everything else? (I didn't add it to `public class Part` in my example though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove [DataMember] attribute from properties which you want to ignore then all such properties will be excluded from deserialization.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a way where I wouldn't even have to list them in my class?